# COPYING values from EXCEL sheet_1 COLUMNS and PUTTING as (comma separated) into EXCEL sheet_2 ROWS

Tags: excel, rows, spreadsheet, multiple-columns

I have an EXCEL sheet_1 like i.e.

[image]

and I want output in another EXCEL sheet_2 in this form i.e.

[image]

All is what I want to delete multiple rows with same `aid` and to put all the `non-zero values` (comma separated) in single cells of each columns named i.e. `1990 - 1994`, `1992 - 1996`.....so on against each `aid` i.e. `2937`, `11120`, `12403`......and so on.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Judging by other questions the data is coming from SQL Server, one of the options is to use SQL engine to perform grouping.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I hope I'll find the time to answer this...

Comment: You are better off normalizing your data in a database with three columns yearspan, aid, amount. You will then be able to manipulate the data any way you want. Please indicate what ultimately you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2723-excel-concatenate-based-on-criteria.html Not the specific code but similar solution. Just customize according to your need.